# How can I describe this pattern?

Tags: terminology, names

I am trying to write a description of the back of a playing card. It includes a band that I am describing as "blue with a white arabesque".

[image: blue band with white arabesque]

This seems like a weak description. I am sure that in the decorative-banding industry, there are probably exact names for these things, but my search-fu is apparently weak.

Can anyone provide a superior description or a pointer to a "catalog of decorative banding" or some such? What is the name of the white pattern? Or, what are the names of the components of the pattern so that I can string them together?

Comment: Perhaps your question is more suited to another Stackexchange site: [**Graphic Design**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). However, I feel that the word **border** or **margin** should be used in reference to the arabesque part of the pattern, if the rest is a simple lattice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too subject-specific-language related for ELU; it belongs perhaps on Graphic Design.

Comment: ***Weak** description?* I'd have thought ***arabesque*** was an exceptionally ***good*** term! If I do a Google "image search" for it, I get hundreds of pictures just like the one in the question. Well, "close enough" to me, but I'm not a graphics design specialist.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's the description I have now, so I'll certainly stay with it if I can't do better. But in this case arabesque is sort of "anything with a bunch of swoopy lines" to me, and I am hoping there is someone else more knowledgeable. Sort of like the difference between saying "a font with no serifs" and saying "comic sans"...

Comment: @AustinHastings seems Victorian to me. Maybe ask/search on Graphic design

Comment: [***Scrollwork**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_(art)) is used in popular language for two-dimensional **decorative flourishes** and **arabesques** of all kinds.* (Wikipedia)

Comment: Do you perhaps know if they are French, British, or German playing cards? Could you upload a picture of the face of the Ace and the King/Queen/Jack?

Comment: @Boondoggle They are spanish cards. (Fournier No. 1 - 40 cards)